# SQL Distinct pairs matched on array of strings

Tags: sql

This is a simplified version of the tables but I have a table called NAME with 2 columns, names (strings) and classes (strings)

| index | name | classes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Joe | Mat 12 |
| 1 | Hector | Mat 12 |
| 2 | Terry | Arc 13 |
| 3 | Elizabeth | Soc 7 |
| 4 | Wyatt | Arc 13 |
| 5 | Alex | His 9 |
| 6 | James | Mat 12 |
| 7 | Rebecca | Soc 7 |

NOTE: All names and classes actually have a numerical ID associated with them, used actual names for illustration.

I want to pair up unique people taking the same class, with the output table looking something like this.

| name1 | name2 | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Hector | Mat 12 |
| Joe | James | Mat 12 |
| Hector | James | Mat 12 |
| Terry | Wyatt | Arc 12 |

Worth noting is that the output table should have unique pairs and a person shouldn't be paired with themselves (so don't want outcome like this)

| name1 | name2 | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Hector | Mat 12 |
| Hector | Joe | Mat 12 |
| Joe | Joe | Mat 12 |

I've tried something along the lines of

```
SELECT NAME.names as name1, NAME.names as name2, NAME.classes as c1, COUNT(*) as pa
FROM NAME 
JOIN NAME 
    ON name1.c1 = name2.c1
       GROUP BY name1, name2
       ORDER BY c1
```

But doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this using a join and comparison based on the index/name

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
     n1.name as name1,
     n2.name as name2,
     n1.classes
FROM
     NAME n1
INNER JOIN
     NAME n2 ON n1.classes=n2.classes AND n1.index < n2.index;
```

| name1 | classes | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Mat 12 | Hector |
| Terry | Arc 13 | Wyatt |
| Joe | Mat 12 | James |
| Hector | Mat 12 | James |
| Elizabeth | Soc 7 | Rebecca |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
     n1.name as name1,
     n2.name as name2,
     n1.classes
FROM
     NAME n1
INNER JOIN
     NAME n2 ON n1.classes=n2.classes AND n1.name < n2.name;
```

| name1 | classes | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hector | Mat 12 | Joe |
| James | Mat 12 | Joe |
| Terry | Arc 13 | Wyatt |
| Hector | Mat 12 | James |
| Elizabeth | Soc 7 | Rebecca |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6D86J4WU9H124fehUKNVcb/1)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Partner got it but yes it did work! Please ignore the time gap in response. Covid was a weird time.